# Angular Universal and Lambda. Images are not showing

Tags: angular, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, assets, angular-universal

I have deployed version of my Angular app. Angular Universal is used for server side rendering and Lambda with ApiGateway. Images that are with  tag are showing good.

```
<div class="search-page__search-wrapper">
    <img src="../../../../../assets/images/toad-icon.svg" />
</div>
```

But when have them as **background-image** they are not showing.

```
.auth-image-wrapper {
  background-image: url('../../../../../assets/images/sign-up-photo.jpg');
}
```

I am using Serveless Framework and I have configured:

**serverless.yml**

```
plugins:
- serverless-apigw-binary
custom:


apigwBinary:
    types:
    - '*/*'
```

**lambda.js**

```
const awsServerlessExpress = require('aws-serverless-express');
const server = require('./dist/funtoad-web/server/main');
const awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require('aws-serverless-express/middleware');


const binaryMimeTypes = [
  'application/javascript',
  'application/json',
  'application/octet-stream',
  'application/xml',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/gif',
  'text/comma-separated-values',
  'text/css',
  'text/html',
  'text/javascript',
  'text/plain',
  'text/text',
  'text/xml',
  'image/x-icon',
  'image/svg+xml',
  'application/x-font-ttf'
];

server.app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext());
const serverProxy = awsServerlessExpress.createServer(server.app, null, binaryMimeTypes);
module.exports.funtoadssr = (event, context) => awsServerlessExpress.proxy(serverProxy, event, context);
```

The Angular App when is running locally is working great.

How do I make this work deployed and locally?

Comment: Why not just use root-relative urls?

Comment: Have you already tried setting the `extractCss` option in your `angular.json`? https://angular.io/cli/build#options - https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MP.Web/ClientApp/angular.json#L26. Without this I used to get a unstyled ssr-response

Comment: @Pieterjan yes that is set up to true, I am getting the other styles only the images are not showing. If I go domain.com/assets/images/sign-up-photo the image is served. So something with the path mapping when getting assets from style

Comment: I'm sorry that's the only thing that comes to my mind. Perhaps you can try to take a look at the source code returned from the server, or inspect your CSS and verify if the url of the images returns the image.

Comment: lol coming across this problem now as well 2 years later